# Можно ли в Scanner передать кодировку?

Tags: java, кодировка, scanner

Можно ли как- то задать что бы Scanner читал из UTF-8;
что-то вроде:

```
 Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    Scanner scn= new Scanner(System.in,charset);
```

или если хотим задать кодировку нужен ридер:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
  Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in, charset);
```

Comment: new Scanner( System.in, "utf-8" ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно, но только почему-то строкой:

```
new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
```

Если у вас уже есть объект `Charset`, используйте

```
new Scanner(System.in, charset.name());
```

Ну или действительно через `Reader` (который также `Readable`):

```
new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in, charset));
```

В любом случае не стесняйтесь [читать документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29).